# Composite Collider trigger works wrongly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a tilemap with components `tilemap collider` and `composite collider` (isTrigger toggled) on it and some simple code for it:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace Game.Controller
{
    public class BiomeZone : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private Biome _biome;

        private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
        {
            if (collision.gameObject.TryGetComponent<PlayerBiomeHandler>(out PlayerBiomeHandler biomeHandler))
            {
                biomeHandler.EnterNewBiome(_biome);
                Debug.Log("Entered");
            }
        }

        private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
        {
            if (collision.gameObject.TryGetComponent<PlayerBiomeHandler>(out PlayerBiomeHandler biomeHandler))
            {
                biomeHandler.ExitBiome();
                Debug.Log("Exited");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that for some reason that I can't figure out, the `OnTriggerExit2D` method executes right after the `OnTriggerEnter2D` method, when the player's collider is still inside one of the composite colliders.[image: Green borders are composite colliders and red arrow is pointing to the player's collider].

As you can see, there are messages to enter and exit the collider, but the player is inside the collider. I think this may be due to some of them being separate from each other, but even if that is the root of the problem, I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The picture shows 4 BiomeZones, are the 2 events triggered by same BiomeZone?

Comment: @shingo Yes, I only entered one of them and got 2 messages.

Comment: what settings did you put on the collider?

Comment: @BugFinder, ```tilemap collider``` has a ```Used by Composite``` tip toggled, ```composite collider``` has a ```is Trigger``` tip toggled, other settings are standart

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/AnougGC

Comment: magic word ..."outlines"